# Parsing long command-line arguments not working with getopt

Tags: bash, getopt, getopts

I want to parse long command-line arguments for a large script as part of my current project. I have never tried getopt before but want to try the first time to make the script look tidy.

Before trying to push getopt on that large project script, I thought of checking it first on a sample script.

In the following example script, parsing short command-line arguments work fine but not the long command-line arguments:

```
#!/bin/bash

options=$(getopt -o d:f:t: -l domain -l from -l to -- "$@")

[ $? -eq 0 ] || { 
    echo "Incorrect options provided"
    exit 1
}

eval set -- "$options"

while true; do
    case "$1" in
    -d|--domain)
        DOMAIN=$2;
        shift
        ;;
    -f|--from)
        FROM=$2;
        shift
        ;;
    -t|--to)
        TO=$2;
        shift
        ;;
    --)
        shift
        break
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Invalid options!!";
        exit 1
        ;;
    esac
    shift
done

echo "Domain is $DOMAIN"
echo "From address is $FROM"
echo "To address is $TO"
exit 0;
```

Output:

```
# ./getopt_check.bash -d hello.com -f from@test.com -t to@test.com
Domain is hello.com
From address is from@test.com
To address is to@test.com

# ./getopt_check.bash --domain hello.com -f from@test.com -t to@test.com
Invalid options!!

# ./getopt_check.bash --domain hello.com --from from@test.com --to to@test.com
Invalid options!!
```

I am expecting the same output as well when parsing long command arguments:

```
Domain is hello.com
From address is from@test.com
To address is to@test.com
```

When debugging:

```
# bash -x getopt_check.bash --domain hello.com -f from@test.com -t to@test.com
++ getopt -o d:f:t: -l domain -l from -l to -- --domain hello.com -f from@test.com -t to@test.com
+ options=' --domain -f '\''from@test.com'\'' -t '\''to@test.com'\'' -- '\''hello.com'\'''
+ '[' 0 -eq 0 ']'
+ eval set -- ' --domain -f '\''from@test.com'\'' -t '\''to@test.com'\'' -- '\''hello.com'\'''
++ set -- --domain -f from@test.com -t to@test.com -- hello.com
+ true
+ case "$1" in
+ DOMAIN=-f
+ shift
+ shift
+ true
+ case "$1" in
+ echo 'Invalid options!!'
Invalid options!!
+ exit 1
```

Here, the issue is passing case switch OR choice `-d|--domain` ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess its your getopt syntax. Use :

`getopt -o d:f:t: -l domain:,from:,to: -- "$@"`

Instead of :

`getopt -o d:f:t: -l domain -l from -l to -- "$@"`